# Camel Rest-DSL (api-doc) - Potential bug

Tags: rest, apache-camel, swagger-ui

I've been using Rest-DSL (Camel v2.18.1) and trying to set up my own RestOperationResponseMsgDefinition so as to have a useful API doc. By setting a class to the responseModel to tell which object will be returned in case of success, its structure is properly shown in the API doc. However, if I create a class that has that object within, all endpoints which mention it as their outputType/responseModel stop showing the correct structure in the API doc and put "string" instead. Like this:

My outputType/responseModel:

```
class Address {
    private Integer id;
    private String descr;
}
```

API-doc snippet:

```
"/addresses" : {
"get" : {
    "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
    "responses" : {
        "200" : {
            "description" : "Success.",
            "schema" : {
                "$ref" : "#/definitions/Address"
            }
        }
        ...
```

In Swagger-UI, the response example value is shown as:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "descr": "string"
}
```

Everything is alright till I create any class having an Address object within! For instance:

```
class Store {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}
```

Now, for the same endpoint mentioned before, I get...

```
"/addresses" : {
"get" : {
    "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
    "responses" : {
        "200" : {
            "description" : "Success.",
            "schema" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "format" : "com.mycompany.integration.domain.Address"
            }
        }
        ...
```

And the following in Swagger-UI as example value:

```
"string"
```

Has anybody ever passed through and solved this? This seems a bug, though...

Comment: I got to a workaround by using ApiModelProperty annotation on my Address attribute in Store class. Yet it feels like very sensitive to changes as we must provide its reference: `class Store {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @ApiModelProperty(reference = "Address")
    private Address address;
}`

Comment: Try with latest Camel release 2.18.x and 2.19.x